# How do I allow date-time filtering on my custom entity's ISO date field

Tags: views, 8, entities

I have a custom entity with a datetime field. This datetime is saved in the database as an ISO string. I would like to use Views on this entity, and select entities with dates before, after, or between certain dates. I see if I make a view against the system log, these options are presented when filtering on Timestamp. How can I enable the same filtering options on my field?

The field definition is:

```
$fields['set_datetime'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('datetime')
  ->setLabel(t('Set DateTime'))
  ->setDescription(t('Date and time fermentor was set.'))
  ->setSettings(array(
    'datetime_type' => 'datetime',
  ))
  ->setDefaultValue('')
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
    'label' => 'above',
    'type' => 'string',
    'weight' => -4,
  ))
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
    'weight' => -4,
  ))
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

Comment: So you have a custom entity type with a datetime as a base field, and not a custom field type?

Comment: Correct. Updated question with the code.

Answer (score 2):

I posted the following as a bug report to Drupal Core

> When a custom entity is created, and one of the fields is a datetime FieldType, views filters are not treating this field like a datetime field, but, instead, like a string. Timestamp Fieldtypes on the other hand are presented with the correct filter options.

The response I received was:

> Yes, it does default to a string. I think the underlying reason is this:
>
> Datetime support comes from the datetime module, so if you want your entity to use that, add a dependency to datetime and override any defaults for your entity in an extension of \Drupal\views\EntityViewsData.
>
> The Views 'date' filter only works for timestamps (hence your timestamp fields work out-of-the-box), so just setting the filter plugin_id to 'date' won't help either.
>
> So this works as designed I think.

Comment: What was the question for which that quote in your answer here was the response? And how does this answer you posted here answer your question here?

Answer (score 1):

After checking your module provided for me on github and some reverse-engineering  I find out the problem is on `create('datetime')` and you should use `create('created')` So the following code

```
$fields['date'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('created')
  ->setLabel(t('DateTime'))
  ->setDescription(t('Date and time.'))
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
    'label' => 'above',
    'type' => 'timestamp',
    'weight' => -4,
  ))
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
    'type' => 'datetime_timestamp',
    'weight' => -4,
  ))
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

Results the below image for me. it seems it's Ok now.

[image]

Comment: The only thing that changes is the field's widget on the Entity addition page. It removes the ability to add a 'time'.

Comment: @KevinNowaczyk I update the answer, try that

Comment: Nope, Views is still filtering as if it was a string.

Comment: @KevinNowaczyk did you clear the cache? because we didn't use string  type anymore

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. I checked the code, uninstalled, reinstalled, cleared cache and it's still the same. I always assumed that the 'view' section was how the entity list and display would treat the field, not Views.

Comment: @KevinNowaczyk I think with this snippet you can add this field as filter on your views and like  other datetime fields choose a criteria for it.  can you provide a screen shot of views filter or upload your module on git I clone and check it on my local ?

Comment: Well that's just weird. I made a module with one entity, where the only field is a datetime field exactly as I had it defined in my actual module. The code works as expected in this one.

Comment: I checked my new module a second time, and it was not working. (https://github.com/Beakerboy/drupal_test/)

Comment: @KevinNowaczyk, thanks for share your test module, I find your problem and update my answer, I hope it could help you.

Comment: The 'created' fieldtype is an extension of a timestamp fieldtype with the added feature that it's default value is 'now'. Maybe what we've learned is the datetime fieldtype has no advantage over a timestamp, but does have disadvantages.

Comment: @KevinNowaczyk but it works, if you search in all core codes you didn't find any `create('datetime')` , this is correct way, please try it.

Comment: Since I don't require the default action of the 'created' fieldtype, I'd say the correct answer is, "you can't. Use the timestamp field that is used by the log, despite Drupal documentation recommending datetime.

Comment: @KevinNowaczyk There is not any sample of `datetime` in no documentation, I checked serveral modules, they all used  `created` ,

Comment: And what about "daterange" fields?